# storing enum in array VS storing in dictionary?

Tags: c#

Assume I have some enum. For example

```
enum MyEnum
{ 
    Item1, 
    Item2, 
    Item3
}
```

I want to "cache" something for each item in the enum. So I do have two options.

Dictionary option:

`Dictionary<MyEnum, /*someStructure*/> cache = new Dictionary<MyEnum, /*someStructure*/>>();`

or Array option:

```
/*someStructure*/[] cache = new /*someStructure*/[Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Length]
```

What are prons and cons of each of these options? In my opinion `Dictionary` option is more readable and easy to use, but slower than `Array` option.

But will `Dictionary` actually be slower? Probably `Dictionary` is "smart" enough to understand that when `enum` is used as a key, then just "array" can be used as underling implementation?

So the question is - will "ugly `array` option" be faster than "straightforward" `Dictionary` option? Well probably I can just test that... But now when I've wrote the question I want to know what others think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dictionany<TKey, TValue>` isn't "smart" and doens't optimize for any given key. The underlighing implementation is always the same.

However, about performance, using `enum` values as key in dictionary is much slower than you might expect, and is **much slower** than storing `Int32` as the key. The reason for this is because the runtime uses heavy reflection to get the hash code of an enum when calling `GetHashCode()`. This if actually found quite bizar.

But all of this doesn't matter when the most readable approach (using the enum as key in a dictionary) is fast enough. And nobody here can answer that question for you. You will have to measure this. Don't do premature optimization and go with the most readable/maintainable pease of code until proven that the solution isn't fast enough for in your situation (which it will probably be).

However, instead of switching to an array, try switching to a dictionary with a `Int32` key:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int,  /*someStructure*/>();

dictionary[(int)MyEnum.Item1] = /*new someStructure()*/;
```

Comment: i am optimizing bottlneck in my program. I do spent 18 microseconds for something I want to spend 1-2 microseconds. I've found that `Dictionary` is used intensive in this part and so now i'm thinking if I should try to substitute it. Dictionary with `int32` key looks odd, why do you suggest that?

Comment: And 18 microsoconds is too much in your situation? What kind of program are your developing?

Comment: But as I said, change the dictionary to hold `int` keys and profile again. This should make a big difference.

Comment: you've said that there would be ~no difference: "using enum values as key in dictionary ... is roughly the same as storing Int32 as the key."

Comment: @javapowered: I'm sorry. That was a typo. It is **much slower** than using an int, because the runtime uses reflection.

Comment: thanks, now i understand :) actually i already tring "pure array" option. so far it's a little bit faster than Dictionary. in my application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective answer, but I would personally use an array over a dictionary when:

1. The underlying values of all the enumeration members are consecutive. Using an array would be unintuitive (and wastes memory) if there are large gaps between the values, such as in:

   `enum MyEnum
   { 
       Units, 
       Tens = 10, 
       Hundreds = 100,
   }`
2. All enumeration members will always have a value in the structure. If they don't, then the dictionary would provide more intuitive semantics for checking for the presence of a particular key through its `TryGetValue` method. (That said, you could alternatively use `null` to indicate absence if the values are a reference type.)